# Query not working in PHP but works in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with this query. If I use this query in MySQL that works fine but is not being executed when used in PHP.

$sql = "INSERT INTO dtable (name, mobile, email) VALUES ('".$MP_Name."', '".$MP_Mobil."','".$MP_Email."');";

$conn->query($sql);

Comment: What error message do you have?

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO dtable(name,mobile,email) VALUES ('$MP_Name','$MP_Mobil','$MP_Email');";

Comment: I don't have any error message. Just skips the insertion query.

Comment: DO NOT EXECUTE a query like that, use pdo and parameters. With a query like that you are opened to sql injections.

Comment: I got that @Giacomo M, but the project was written a long before and experiencing issue from just some days and was working fine before.

Comment: As said @Giacomo M, refer to this page to avoid sql injections: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: what are the values of your variables? $MP_Name, $MP_Mobile and $MP_Email?

Comment: Anil Nepal, +6146*******, anil@gmail.com

Comment: I got this error now: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Answer (score 1):

Use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to avoid sql injection.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO dtable (name, mobile, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $MP_Name, $MP_Mobil, $MP_Email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo the query string before executing it and copy/paste that echoed query in phpmyadmin and check for errors in the query

```
 $result= $sql->query(sprintf("INSERT INTO dtable(name,mobile,email) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')", ($_POST['MP_Name']), ($_POST['MP_Mobil']), ($_POST['MP_Email'])));
 echo $sql;
```

Comment: I tried that. It gives no error in phpmyadmin and works fine there.

Answer (score 0):

With more study, I came to know that I was actually getting an error; commands out of sync; you can't run this command now.

I added $conn->next_result() before running the query which solved the issue.